# .NetCore 3.1 project files not showing after creation VS2019 --

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, sdk, runtime, 64-bit

The problem is that - I'm creating a new web application[.netcore v3.1] project in VS2019.
The project files are not showing. What I instantly see under the solution node is 'connected services'.

I can see the files and folders only if I click the 'show all files' tab on the top.
trying to do 'Include in Project' individually on the files but that fails. For ref. see the image I attached.  --->     https://pasteboard.co/JR4fXs2.png

what's the catch? Anything with sdks or runtimes installed? how do I get this to display normally as expected. when does this above anomaly occur.

The .csproj file added -

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>blablablabla ..... </UserSecretsId>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.11" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.json" />
    <None Include="Startup.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Can you include the content of your `.csproj` file?

Comment: added .csproj file for cross checking  @eduherminio

Comment: went through one link discussing a similar scenario, that prescribes uninstall of all the installed .netcore sdks and reinstall them. specially the previews. Drastic.